# Foreign Key constraint fails when trying to delete multiple rows from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, sql-delete, multiple-tables

I want to delete the corresponding rows in `staff`, `login` and `jobs` depending on the `Staff.StaffID`, given that `StaffID` and `LoginID` are foreign keys within `jobs`. Furthermore, `StaffID` is a foreign key within `login` too. When I use the following query, I get an error about foregin key constraint failing. Any ideas?

SQL:

```
DELETE jobs, login, staff 
FROM jobs 
    INNER JOIN login 
WHERE login.LoginID=jobs.loginID 
AND staff.StaffID = '18';
```

Obviously this is incomplete. I wanted to continue INNER JOINING before the AND, in order to inner join login.StaffID = staff.StaffID as well as staff.StaffID = jobs.JobID. However, when I do this, I get an error:

```
DELETE jobs, login, staff 
FROM jobs 
    INNER JOIN login, staff 
WHERE login.LoginID=jobs.LoginID 
AND staff.StaffID=login.StaffID 
AND staff.StaffID = login.LoginID 
AND staff.StaffID = '18';
```

Which gives the error: "#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`younglife`.`login`, CONSTRAINT `FK_59` FOREIGN KEY (`StaffID`) REFERENCES `staff` (`StaffID`))"

I can tell that this is inefficent, and I was wondering what is the best way to approach this. Thanks.

Comment: Please show su what errors go with what attempts, just saying I get an error is not really helpful

Comment: You should use `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your foreign key constraints. Then it will delete the related rows automatically, you don't need the join.

Comment: If you use the join, it won't necessarily delete them in the correct order, so it tries to delete the parent rows before the dependent rows, and you get this error.

Comment: You should also have a separate `INNER JOIN` for each table: `INNER JOIN login ON login.loginID = jobs.loginID INNER JOIN staff ON staff.staffID = login.StaffID`.

Comment: How do I format the query in order to DELETE ON CASCADE? Many tutorials talk about inserting and creating tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run three deletes:

```
DELETE j
    FROM jobs j JOIN
         login l
         ON l.LoginID = j.LoginID 
    WHERE l.StaffID = 18;

DELETE l
   FROM login l
   WHERE l.StaffID = 18;

DELETE s
    FROM staff s
    WHERE s.StaffID = 18;
```

Be sure that you do the deletions in the correct order.

Comment: Hi Gordon, the first two delete statements work, however MySQL cannot find the table s?